how sharepoint build search link description
in sharepoint 2019 search results under any link there is description showing some lines
how sharepoint 2019 is chose what words to be description and how to modify it
I cheche search databases for link description but didn't find it

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
